# Problems with swc transpiler in node express.js with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize-typescript, swc

I'm using Sequelize to create a database to register users, but I'm running into a problem while transpiling the code, I get the below console error.

```
[1] C:\Users\GONZALO\Desktop\proyecto_catalogador\got-take-profit\backend\node-take-profit-api-auth\dist\models\user.js:8
[1]         return _default;
[1]         ^
[1]
[1] ReferenceError: Cannot access '_default' before initialization
[1]     at Object.get [as default] (C:\Users\GONZALO\Desktop\proyecto_catalogador\got-take-profit\backend\node-take-profit-api-auth\dist\models\user.js:8:9)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GONZALO\Desktop\proyecto_catalogador\got-take-profit\backend\node-take-profit-api-auth\dist\models\role.js:59:26)
[1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
[1]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
[1]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
[1]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GONZALO\Desktop\proyecto_catalogador\got-take-profit\backend\node-take-profit-api-auth\dist\models\user.js:13:54)
[1]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[1] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The models causing the problem in question.

```
User Model:

import {Model, DataTypes} from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../configs/database';
import Role from './role';
import Subscription from './subscription';

class User extends Model {
    public id!: number;
    public username!: string;
    public email!: string;
    public password!: string;
    public createDate!: Date;
    public lastLogin!: Date;
    public sessionDuration!: number;
    public idRole!: number;
    public idSubscription!: number;



    public readonly roles?: Role[];
    public readonly subscriptions?: Subscription;
}

User.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
        },

        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull:false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                isEmail: true,
            }
        },

        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        
        createDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        },

        lastLogin: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
          },

        sessionDuration: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0,
        },

        idRole: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
        },

        idSubscription: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'users',
        sequelize,
    }
);


User.belongsToMany(Role, {through: 'UserRole'});
User.belongsTo(Subscription);

User.addHook('beforeCreate', async (users: User) => {
    const defaultRole = await Role.findOne({where: {name: 'user'}});
    if (defaultRole) {
      users.idRole = defaultRole.id;
    }
  });

export default User;

===================================================================================

Role model:

import {Model, DataTypes} from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../configs/database';
import User from './user';

class Role extends Model {
    public id!: number;
    public name!: string;
    public userId!: number;

    public readonly users?: User[];
    
}

Role.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },

        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: false,
        },

        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
        }
       
    },
    {
        tableName: 'users',
        sequelize,
    }
);

Role.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserRole'});

export default Role;
```

Below is my package.json and the transpiled code.

```
Package.json:

{
  "name": "node-take-profit-api-auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/server.ts",
 
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "concurrently \"pnpm run watch-compile\" \"pnpm run watch-dev\"",
    "watch-compile": "swc src -w --out-dir dist",
    "watch-dev": "nodemon --watch \"dist/**/*\" -e js ./dist/server.js",
    "build": "swc src -d dist",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js"
    
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.11.2",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@swc/cli": "^0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.73",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.5",
    "@types/pg": "^8.10.2",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.15",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

```
Transpiled Code:

user.js:

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "default", {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
        return _default;
    }
});
const _sequelize = require("sequelize");
const _database = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("../configs/database"));
const _role = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("./role"));
const _subscription = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("./subscription"));
function _define_property(obj, key, value) {
    if (key in obj) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            value: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true
        });
    } else {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}
function _interop_require_default(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
        default: obj
    };
}
class User extends _sequelize.Model {
    constructor(...args){
        super(...args);
        _define_property(this, "id", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "username", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "email", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "password", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "createDate", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "lastLogin", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "sessionDuration", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "idRole", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "idSubscription", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "roles", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "subscriptions", void 0);
    }
}
User.init({
    id: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    },
    createDate: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: _sequelize.DataTypes.NOW
    },
    lastLogin: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: _sequelize.DataTypes.NOW
    },
    sessionDuration: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    idRole: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    idSubscription: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'users',
    sequelize: _database.default
});
User.belongsToMany(_role.default, {
    through: 'UserRole'
});
User.belongsTo(_subscription.default);
User.addHook('beforeCreate', async (users)=>{
    const defaultRole = await _role.default.findOne({
        where: {
            name: 'user'
        }
    });
    if (defaultRole) {
        users.idRole = defaultRole.id;
    }
});
const _default = User;


=====================================================================================

role.js:

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "default", {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
        return _default;
    }
});
const _sequelize = require("sequelize");
const _database = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("../configs/database"));
const _user = /*#__PURE__*/ _interop_require_default(require("./user"));
function _define_property(obj, key, value) {
    if (key in obj) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            value: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true
        });
    } else {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}
function _interop_require_default(obj) {
    return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
        default: obj
    };
}
class Role extends _sequelize.Model {
    constructor(...args){
        super(...args);
        _define_property(this, "id", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "name", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "userId", void 0);
        _define_property(this, "users", void 0);
    }
}
Role.init({
    id: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    },
    userId: {
        type: _sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'users',
    sequelize: _database.default
});
Role.belongsToMany(_user.default, {
    through: 'UserRole'
});
const _default = Role;
```

I can't fix it, help is appreciated!

I have tried to modify the transpiled code but it transpiles again and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of circular dependencies (`User` imports `Role`, `Role` imports `User`), there are 2 ways about it -

1. Define both the Models in one file
2. If you're okay with commonJS output, you can export it with commonJS syntax like so -

```ts
export = { Role };
```

Check [this issue](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/5047) for more details.